# Tensorflow TF_SessionRun error problem zsh: segmentation fault

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to run the  TF_SessionRun method from this  code:

```
std::vector<float> NeuralNetwork::predict(const std::vector<float> &inputs)
{
    // Assuming the input is already preprocessed and has the correct shape
    std::cout << "Predicting Called" << std::endl;

    // Step 1: Create Tensors for inputs
    int64_t dims[] = {1, 224, 224, 3}; // Adjusted shape for the input tensor based on ImageProcessor

    // Use unique_ptr to manage the Tensor resources
    std::unique_ptr<TF_Tensor, decltype(&TF_DeleteTensor)> input_tensor(
        TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, inputs.size() * sizeof(float)),
        TF_DeleteTensor);
    std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 1" << std::endl;
    memcpy(TF_TensorData(input_tensor.get()), inputs.data(), TF_TensorByteSize(input_tensor.get()));
    std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 1.1" << std::endl;

    // Step 2: Setup running the session
    std::vector<TF_Output> input_ops = {{TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "serving_default_conv2d_12_input:0"), 0}};
    std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 2.1" << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TF_Tensor, decltype(&TF_DeleteTensor)>> input_values;
    input_values.push_back(std::move(input_tensor));
    std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 2.2" << std::endl;

    std::vector<TF_Tensor *> input_values_raw;
    for (auto &unique_tensor : input_values)
    {
        input_values_raw.push_back(unique_tensor.get());
    }

    std::vector<TF_Output> output_ops = {{TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall:0"), 0}};

    std::vector<TF_Tensor *> raw_output_values(output_ops.size(), nullptr);
    std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 2.3" << std::endl;

    // Step 3: Run the session
    std::cout << input_ops.size() << "size of input" << std::endl;
    std::cout << output_ops.size() << "size of output" << raw_output_values.size() << std::endl;


       
        TF_SessionRun(session,
                      nullptr, // run options
                      input_ops.data(), input_values_raw.data(), input_ops.size(),
                      output_ops.data(), raw_output_values.data(), raw_output_values.size(),
                      nullptr, 0, // target operations, number of targets
                      nullptr,    // run metadata
                      status      // output status
        );
        std::cout << "Predicting Called debug 3.1" << std::endl;

        if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error running session: " << TF_Message(status) << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
 

    // Step 4: Transfer the ownership of output tensors
    // Step 4: Transfer the ownership of output tensors to smart pointers
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TF_Tensor, decltype(&TF_DeleteTensor)>> output_values;
    for (TF_Tensor *tensor : raw_output_values)
    {
        output_values.emplace_back(tensor, TF_DeleteTensor);
    }

    // Extract the results from the output tensor
    float *output_data = static_cast<float *>(TF_TensorData(output_values[0].get()));
    std::vector<float> results(output_data, output_data + TF_TensorByteSize(output_values[0].get()) / sizeof(float));

    return results;
}
```

Even with mock inputs like such

```
// Mock input
    std::vector<float> mockInput(1 * 224 * 224 * 3, 0.5);  // A tensor with all values as 0.5

    // Call the predict function
    std::vector<float> output = nn.predict(mockInput);

    // Print the output (for testing purposes)
    for (float val : output) {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? From the debugging tracing, TF_SessionRun is the culprit. I can only think of maybe the input and outputs arguments being the problem.

If I am correctly setting the arguments then, where is the segmentation fault coming from?